# FirefoxADM not applying settings - Using Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, firefox

I've followed the deployment instructions on:
http://homepages.ed.ac.uk/mcs/FirefoxADM/ADM_Deploy.pdf

I've applied some settings to a GPO:
[settings http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1c1ac4e777.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1c1ac4e777.png)

However,
When I do GPUPDATE, log out, log back in, nothing has changed...?
Am I missing something?

I'm using Firefox 3.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Does not look like you followed the instructions perfectly. Rename the files from .lgns to .vbs to start. firefox_login.vbs should be under User Configuration and login script not Computer Configuration.  Fix that, gpupdate /force the  target machine, and reboot.  Might take another reboot to apply the settings.  gpresult to ensure the policy's are applied if you are still having issues.

Comment: i have renamed them to .vbs (i did this just after i took screenshot) - should the firefox_startup.vbs still be in Computer Configuration / Policies / Windows Settings / Scripts or should i move this one to the user config too?

Comment: As per the instructions: If you wish to lock down settings in Firefox, add the firefox_startup.vbs script
to Startup Scripts (Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Scripts).
If you wish to set default settings in Firefox, add the firefox_login.vbs script to
Login Scripts (User Configuration/Windows Settings/Scripts).